# Terraform --Create multiple hosted zoned and assign different records for each zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform and trying to change the existing script were we used to create 1 route 53 zone and corresponding route 53 record , now the requirement is to add one more zone and 53 record (correspondingly) , i am trying multi level map , i need your help correct my code

```
tf.vars
variable  "facade_hostname" = {
   type = "map"
   default = {
     old_mobile_facade_hostname = "xxx.morgen.nl" 
     new_mobile_facade_hostname = "xxx.test.nl" 
  }
}


dns_config = {

    old_dns_records  = {
      mobile_facade = {
        name    = "xxx.morgen.nl",
        ttl     = "5",
        type    = "A",
        records = [
          "1.2.3.4"]
      }
    },

    new_dns_records  = {
      mobile_facade = {
        name    = "xxx.test.nl",
        ttl     = "5",
        type    = "A",
        records = [
          "5.6.7.8"]
      }
    }

}
```

```
varibles.tf

variable "dns_config" {
  type    = map(object({
    name  = string
    ttl =   string
    type  = string
    records = string
  }))
  default = {}
}

variable "facade_hostname" {
  type    = map(object({
    old_mobile_facade_hostname  = string
    new_mobile_facade_hostname =   string
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

and finally my resource creation

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "private" {
  for_each = var.facade_hostname
  count = var.dns_config != "" && var.facade_hostname != "" ? 1 : 0
  name          = var.facade_hostname
  force_destroy = true
  vpc {
    vpc_id = module.vpc_private.vpc_id
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "A" {
   for_each = var.facade_hostname
  count   = var.dns_config != "" && var.facade_hostname!= "" ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.private[count.index].zone_id
  name    = var.dns_config.facade_hostname.name
  ttl     = var.dns_config.facade_hostname.ttl
  type    = var.dns_config.facade_hostname.type
  records = var.dns_config.facade_hostname.records

  allow_overwrite = true
}
```

Error i am encountering, when running the terraform init

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of "count" and "for_each"
│
│   on route53.tf line 2, in resource "aws_route53_zone" "private":
│    2:   for_each = var.facade_hostname
│
│ The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only one
│ should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be created.
╵

╷
│ Error: Invalid combination of "count" and "for_each"
│
│   on route53.tf line 12, in resource "aws_route53_record" "A":
│   12:    for_each = var.facade_hostname
│
│ The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only one
│ should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be created.
╵

aws-vault: error: exec: Failed to wait for command termination: exit status 1
```

Thanks

Comment: You mention, you need help with correcting your code. Do you get an error when you run terraform apply or terraform plan? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Thanks paul , i have added the error which i am encountering in the OP, any advice much appreciated

Comment: The obvious error is that you cannot use `count` and `for_each` together and that is what documentation says as well: `Note: A given resource or module block cannot use both count and for_each.`. So you might want to spend some time going through the docs first and then revisit the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after spending some time , this seems a working solution incase if it helps any one in future , to create couple of hosted zone and create different A record based on hosted zone,

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "private" {
  for_each      = var.mobile_facade_hostname
  name          = each.key
  force_destroy = true
  vpc {
    vpc_id = module.vpc_private.vpc_id
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "A" {
  for_each = aws_route53_zone.private
  zone_id  = each.value["zone_id"]
  name     = trimsuffix(each.value["name"], ".")
  type     = "A"
  ttl      = "5"
  records  = [var.mobile_facade_hostname[trimsuffix(each.value["name"], ".")]]
```

My tfvars

```
mobile_facade_hostname  = { "x.y.nl" = "1.2.3.4", "a.b.nl" = "5.6.7.8" }
```

variables.tf

```
variable "mobile_facade_hostname" {
  type    = map(string)
  default = {}
}
```